# "npm install" hangs on sill: idealTree build

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to solve this over the last two days, or so, with no effect:

[image]

Solution that I have attempted include:

- Deleting the package-lock.json file
- Coordinating with the other dev on the project to align the Node.js
  version and reinstalling the whole framework
- Using --verbose as part of the `npm i` command
- Editing environmental variables to add NPM to them
- Deleting the "node_modules" folder (with `rm -rf node_modules/`)
- Disabling, then re-enabling SSH
- Trying with and without VPN being active
- Clearing the cache via the command line, i.e. the node_modules step
  above

This is a link to another topic on the same issue on SO that also seems to be outstanding: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973352/npm-install-hangs-on-idealtree-step)

I've reviewed the range of discussions on SO about the problem, to no particular avail, and I think I'm out of options. Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue was the connection to registry.npmjs.org, after the installation attempt finally processed.

[image]

The solution is that when you go to run "npm install", you have to add "registry.npmjs.org" at the end of it, and it sums up to:

**npm i registry.npmjs.org**

Make sure to run this from the folder of your NodeJS project.

Other useful links to consult:

[NPM stuck on idealTree: timing idealTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69161318/npm-stuck-on-idealtree-timing-idealtree)

[npm install hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs)

[stop "npm install" at [..................] | idealTree:regal: sill idealTree buildDeps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678583/stop-npm-install-at-idealtreeregal-sill-idealtree-bui)

[Error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592908/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmjs-org443) --this one is for Angular, but still relevant.

As a final curiosity, going to registry.npmjs.org leads to this site:
[image]

where as https://www.npmjs.com/package/registry.npmjs.org leads to

[image]

You will note the command I used in this solution on the right side of that last screenshot.

Finally:
[image]

There is a typo in the error output: error refers to "registry.n**PJM**s.org", whereas the address **has to be** "registry.n**PMJ**s.org".
I don't know if this should be brought to the attention of NodeJS devs, but there you go.

Comment: What if it's happening when you want to install a package?

Answer (score 81):

**On MacOS (M1 chip)** switching the IPV6 from `Automatically` to `Link-local only` fixed a very similar issue. When I tried adding `registry.npmjs.org`, npm was similarly getting "stuck".

To apply this setting go to `System Preferences` >> `Network` >> press `Advanced` >> `TCP/IP` tab >>  on `Configure IPv6` select `Link-local only` and apply

I found this solution in [this thread](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3359#issuecomment-1248194982)

Comment: This helped!!! And I am on Intel

Comment: M2 Pro helped, thank you. On the new MacOs its `Wi-Fi`>>`Details`>>`TCP/IP`>>`Configure IPv6 select Link-local only`

Comment: Have a cookie 

Comment: M1 pro confirmed

Comment: Doesnt work in Macbook Air M1

Comment: @code.cycling I have a Macbook Air M1 and validated the solution on this machine. I assume your case is a slightly different configuration issue that does not depend on the hardware

Comment: Hey thanks, this helped solve the hang-ups for me. Do you know why this would fix the problem?

Comment: Next.js 14.1 was hanging up on install with npx. This worked on my M1 Macbook air, using @unglued MacOs instructions

Answer (score 24):

On Ubuntu 22.10, disabling IPv6 fixed this for me.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

To do this permanently, edit `/etc/default/grub`: change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"
```

and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked on my Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon too

Comment: Thank you; this worked for me as well on Linux Mint.

Comment: Legend.  still working in 2024.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to `node\node_modules\npm\.npmrc`:

```
strict-ssl=false
```

See [How to install NodeJS LTS on Windows as a local user (without admin rights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029089/how-to-install-nodejs-lts-on-windows-as-a-local-user-without-admin-rights) for details.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a weird internet connection problem. I tried to use a 4G sharing with my phone and tried to run npm install again, it worked. This way I was sure the problem was related to my connection set up and not node installation.

I unplugged my ethernet cable for 20s, plugged it in again and it worked, surprisingly.

Answer (score 4):

Disconnecting from my VPN connection resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Running `npm set strict-ssl false` in Command Prompt worked for me

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing this on ubuntu or linux mint, my problem was that there was not a .npmrc file in the root users home directory. I am not sure why this isn't automatically placed there, as npm needs root permissions to write to the most of the file system.

Here is my .npmrc file in my users home directory

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/                                                                                            
strict-ssl=false
```

to copy .npmrc file to the root home directory run

```
sudo cp ~/.npmrc /.npmrc
```

You can then install packages as root without getting stuck, as it now knows the correct registry URL.

Answer (score 1):

Was having a similar issue when trying to run `npm install` on Windows while using a cellular hotspot of my iPhone.

Was indeed able to fix it by disabling IPv6 on Windows 11:

To Disable IPv6:

- Use the shortcut, Windows Key + X to open the Control Panel.
- Open Network and Internet.
- Open Network and Sharing Center.
- Click Change Adapter Settings.
- Right-click your connection and go to Properties.
- Uncheck the box next to Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that might cause this is if you have incorrectly formatted certificates added to your npm config.

To check if this is a problem you can run

```
npm config get cert
npm config get key
```

To check if there is a value there, and if they look right.

If you're not sure, make a note of the values so you can restore if necessary and then remove them from the config

```
npm config delete cert
npm config delete key
```

Then try npm install again

To add the config back use

```
npm config set cert "<cert>"
npm config set key "<key>"
```

substituting you actual cert and key, (not the file, but the cert and key text)
more info on npm config here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#cert

Comment: What if they are null from the beginning?

Comment: sorry I missed this in November.  
Not sure I understand the question though. 

If the cert and key are null then running `npm config get cert` will return undefined.  So you will know.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was disabling the ipV6 protocol on my network, this on windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

If `npm install` seems to be stalling, it might be due to a slow network connection.

When you execute `npm --verbose install`, you may see output such as:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table 104ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 105ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2futils 21950ms (cache updated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2ftypescript-estree 57954ms (cache updated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2ftypes 480928ms (cache updated)
```

In this case, a few caches had to be refreshed, and the corresponding HTTP responses were of considerable size. For instance, `/@typescript-eslint%2ftypesw` is around 40 MB.

Answer (score -1):

[solved] I read many and test many things also I checked ping to registry.npmjs.org and it was fine
so it was solved by changing the network!
I hotspot mobile data instead of wifi so it worked very well