# npm install xyz" hanging on "idealTree:project-name: sill idealTree buildDeps"

Tags: npm

everytime i run the installation command, it hangs on "idealTree:project-name: sill idealTree buildDeps" forever.

Trying to install a few npm packages in my project like express, mysql2, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It will eventually finish and show an error message and error log location. You can also visit these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs/71036319) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865039/npm-install-hangs-on-sill-idealtree-build) to see several answers to this question.